# When is it better to use zip instead of izip?

Tags: python-2.7, python-2.x, python-itertools

When is it better to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) instead of [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)?

Comment: One reason in favor of `zip` , too obvious yet still worth pointing out, is that `izip` returns an `iterator` which can be traversed only once.  i.e. in `ii = izip(a,b) ; f(ii) ; g(ii)`, here an empty list `[]` is passed to `g`.

Comment: FYI, Python 3's `zip` function is Python 2's `izip`.  In general Python 3 changed most functions to use iterators, like range, filter, the dict functions, etc

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When you know you'll want the full list of items constructed (for instance, for passing to a function that would modify that list in-place). Or when you want to force the arguments you're passing to `zip()` to be completely evaluated at that specific point.

Comment: Would it not be better to use izip in the first case as its faster since it reuses the tuple and there's no real reason not to use izip?

Comment: @user1815201: `izip` only reuses the `tuple` if the `tuple` was released before the next iteration begins, so it doesn't gain you anything. That said, any loss is trivial too, so I agree that there is little reason not to use `izip` exclusively, wrapping with `list` if you need a `list`; you can actually do this the "proper" way by adding `from future_builtins import zip` to Py2 code, which makes plain `zip` into `izip` (preparing for Py3 transition).

Answer (score 103):

`zip` computes all the list at once, `izip` computes the elements only when requested.

One important difference is that 'zip' returns an actual list, 'izip' returns an 'izip object', which is not a list and does not support list-specific features (such as indexing):

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> z = zip(l1, l2)
>>> iz = izip(l1, l2)
>>> isinstance(zip(l1, l2), list)
True
>>> isinstance(izip(l1, l2), list)
False
>>> z[::2] #Get odd places
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> iz[::2] #Same with izip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'itertools.izip' object is unsubscriptable
```

So, if you need a list (an not a list-like object), just use 'zip'.

Apart from this, 'izip' can be useful for saving memory or cycles.

E.g. the following code may exit after few cycles, so there is no need to compute all items of combined list:

```
lst_a = ... #list with very large number of items
lst_b = ... #list with very large number of items
#At each cycle, the next couple is provided
for a, b in izip(lst_a, lst_b):
    if a == b:
        break
print a
```

using `zip` would have computed **all** `(a, b)` couples before entering the cycle.

Moreover, if `lst_a` and `lst_b` are very large (e.g. millions of records), `zip(a, b)` will build a third list with double space.

But if you have small lists, maybe `zip` is faster.

Comment: You're right. I started with good intentions and then fell into theoretical stuff...

Answer (score 7):

The itertools library provides "iterators" for common Python functions. From the itertools docs, "Like zip() except that it returns an iterator instead of a list." The I in izip() means "iterator".

Python iterators are a "lazy loaded" sequence that saves memory over regular in-memory list. So, you would use itertools.izip(a, b) when the two inputs a, b are too big to keep in memory at one time.

Look up the Python concepts related to efficient sequential processing:

```
"generators" & "yield"
"iterators"
"lazy loading"
```

Comment: Nicely explained.

Answer (score 5):

In 2.x, when you *need* a list instead of an iterator.

Comment: Can you give me an example where that might happen?

Comment: Not really. Which is why I tend to prefer `itertools.izip()` except where the gains would be purely statistical.

Comment: One case, when you need a list, is when you plan to access items of the result by index or need to find total length. `lst = zip(lst_a, lst_b)` allows `lst[1]` or `len(lst)`. However, for `ilst = itertools.izip(lst_a, lst_n)` you will fail trying to `ilst[1]` or `len(ilst)`.