# python concatenate substrings by two lists with given start and end positions

Tags: python, string, list, substring, concatenation

Hello to Masters of Python!

As the title says, I have to concatenate substrings with the information provided in two lists of start and end position, respectively.

For example,

```
string     = 'AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJKKKK'
start_list = [0,8,16,24]
end_list   = [4,12,20,28]
```

The end result should be like

```
print (string[0:4]+string[8:12]+string[16:20]+string[24:28])
```

AAAACCCCEEEEGGGG

if the start and end positions increase, I have to do it with for loop
iterating start and end positions of each elements in the two lists.

Could you please help me go through this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
''.join(string[a:b] for a, b in zip(start_list, end_list))
```

`zip` combines multiple iterators:

```
print zip(start_list, end_list)
> [(0, 4), (8, 12), (16, 20), (24, 28)]
```

If the list of indexes is long, you might want to use `izip`. See: [When is it better to use zip instead of izip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989763/python-izip-vs-zip)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce` and `zip` to do this:

```
In [1]: timeit reduce(lambda s, (i, j): s + string[i:j], zip(start_list, end_list), '')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.67 μs per loop
```

This iterates through each `(start, stop)` pair of indices, and concatenates the substring of `string` given by those indices together.

Similarly, you could use a list comprehension or a generator and `join`:

```
In [3]: # generator
In [4]: timeit ''.join( string[i:j] for i, j in zip(start_list, end_list) )
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.43 μs per loop
In [5]: # list comprehension
In [6]: timeit ''.join([ string[i:j] for i, j in zip(start_list, end_list) ])
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 μs per loop
```

Finally, you could use @gnibbler's answer that uses string slicing:

```
In [7]: #slicing
In [8]: timeit ''.join(map(string.__getslice__, start_list, end_list))
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 μs per loop
```

Using `timeit`, the fastest way appears to be to using list slicing and `join`, followed by `join` and a list comprehension, and then `reduce`.

Comment: Can you try timing my answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> ''.join(map(string.__getslice__, start_list, end_list))
'AAAACCCCEEEEGGGG'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join), you can easily achieve this:

```
''.join([string[v:end_list[i]] for i, v in enumerate(start_list)])
```

Or, you can just use the built-in [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
''.join([string[start:end] for start, end in zip(start_list, end_list)])
```

Demo - List Comprehension:

```
>>> a =''.join([string[v:end_list[i]] for i, v in enumerate(start_list)])
>>> print(a)
AAAACCCCEEEEGGGG
```

Using `zip()`:

```
>>> a = ''.join([string[start:end] for start, end in zip(start_list, end_list)])
>>> print(a)
AAAACCCCEEEEGGGG
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers already provided, you can also do:

```
''.join(map(lambda a,b: string[a:b], start_list, end_list))
```