# Nested Tuples... Multiply two tuples and store in 3rd... How to do it..?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Create a tuple of grocery shopping items:

1. `total_price` = `qty*price` (to be calculated).
2. Calculate the grand total (total bill amount).
3. Identify the costliest and the cheapest item.

Here is the code:

```py
grocery = (
    ('butter', 'maggi', 'T-Shirt', 'Chocolate', 'Sanitizer'),
    (12, 10, 250, 80, 15),
    (10, 5, 2, 2, 5),   
    ()
)
merged_tuple = ((i[0], i[1], i[2],i[1]*i[2]) for i in grocery)
merged_tuple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the total price you can do the follow:

```
merged_tuple = (grocery[0],grocery[1], grocery[2], tuple(l * r for l, r in zip(grocery[1], grocery[2])))

merged_tuple
```

See this answer: [Python Multiply tuples of equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553887/python-multiply-tuples-of-equal-length)

With numpy:

```
merged_tuple = (grocery[0],grocery[1], grocery[2], tuple(np.array(grocery[1]) * np.array(grocery[2])))
```

Output:

```
(('butter', 'maggi', 'T-Shirt', 'Chocolate', 'Sanitizer'),
(12, 10, 250, 80, 15),
(10, 5, 2, 2, 5),
(120, 50, 500, 160, 75))
```

Comment: You can use zip, map or numpy, but I think you need a function to do what you want

Comment: @MiteshShah Did I answer to your question? If yes can you please accept my answer? Thank you

Comment: Yes!! Thank-you so much!!

Comment: merged_tuple=(('butter',  'maggi',  'Milk',  'Eggs',  'Chocolates'),
 (7, 10, 2, 12, 11),
 (3, 97, 24, 83, 81))


Here is nested tuple with items in 1st, 2nd is quantity and 3rd is the price...
How can I print the costliest item (i.e Item having highest price)


if(merged_tuple[0]==max(merged_tuple[2])):
    print(merged_tuple[0])


I tried this code but it is not working... Please Help

Comment: import numpy as np; print(merged_tuple[0][np.argmax(merged_tuple[2])])