# Write list of dictionary into CSV Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Suppose I have the list of dictionary dataset like this,

```
data_set = [
    {'Active rate': [0.98, 0.97, 0.96]},
    {'Operating Expense': [3.104, 3.102, 3.101]}
]
```

I need to iterate the list of dictionary and put the keys as column headers and its values as the rows and write it to the CSV file.

```
Active rate    Operating Expense
0.98           3.104
0.97           3.102
0.96           3.101
```

This is what I tried

```
data_set = [
    {'Active rate': [0.98, 0.931588, 0.941192]},
    {'Operating Expense': [3.104, 2.352, 2.304]}
]

import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Active rate', 'Operating Expense']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Active rate': 0.98, 'Operating Expense': 3.102})
    writer.writerow({'Active rate': 0.97, 'Operating Expense': 3.11})
    writer.writerow({'Active rate': 0.96, 'Operating Expense': 3.109})
```

For brevity, I have reduced the keys to 2 and list of values to 3.

How to approach this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: Do you want to know how to write each row somehow automatically instead of putting the values manually together?

Comment: Yes. I need to know how to write each row automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> data_set = [
>     {'Active rate': [0.98, 0.97, 0.96]},
>     {'Operating Expense': [3.104, 3.102, 3.101]}
> ]
> ```

Firstly, just a quick comment, your initial data structure doesn't necessarily make sense as it is. You're using a list of dicts, but each dict seems to be using only one key, which seems to defeat its purpose.

Other data structures that would make more sense would be something like this (where each dict structure is used, as you currently have it, for one label/value pair, but at least the dict is used to tell the label and the value):

```
data_set = [
    {'label': 'Active rate', 'values': [0.98, 0.97, 0.96]},
    {'label': 'Operating Expense', 'values': [3.104, 3.102, 3.101]}
]
```

or, possibly better, an `OrderedDict` that give you both the order of your initial data set and the key/value mapping benefits:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data_set = OrderedDict()
data_set['Active rate'] = [0.98, 0.97, 0.96]
data_set['Operating Expense'] = [3.104, 3.102, 3.101]
```

Of course, we don't always choose the data structures we get, so let's assume you can't change it. Your question then becomes a problem of swapping the roles of rows and columns from your initial dataset. Effectively, you want to iterate through multiple lists at the same time, and for this, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is very useful.

```
import csv

fieldnames = []
val_lists = []
for d in data_set:
    # Find the only used key.
    # This is a bit awkward because of the initial data structure.
    k = d.keys()[0]
    fieldnames.append(k)
    val_lists.append(d[k])

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)    
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    for row in zip(*val_lists):
        # This picks one item from each list and builds a list.
        # The first row will be [0.98, 3.104]
        # The second row will be [0.97, 3.102]
        # ...
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Note that there is no need for a `DictWriter` when you're using `zip`, since that would mean you need to rebuild a dict without any real benefit.

Comment: You could also do the last part more concisely using `writerows(zip(*val_lists))` as @MartinEvans suggested.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach should work for the data structure you have given:

```
import csv

data_set = [
    {'Active rate': [0.98, 0.97, 0.96]},
    {'Operating Expense': [3.104, 3.102, 3.101]}
]

fieldnames = ['Active rate', 'Operating Expense']
rows = []

for field in fieldnames:
    for data in data_set:
        try:
            rows.append(data[field])
            break
        except KeyError, e:
            pass

with open('names.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(fieldnames)
    csv_output.writerows(zip(*rows))
```

Giving you the following CSV output file:

```
Active rate,Operating Expense
0.98,3.104
0.97,3.102
0.96,3.101
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d1 = {'Active rate': [0.98, 0.931588, 0.941192]}
d2 = {'Operating Expense': [3.104, 2.352, 2.304]}

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = zip(d1, d2)[0]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in zip(d1['Active rate'], d2['Operating Expense']):
        writer.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, row)))
```

For performance, you might want to use `itertools.izip` over `zip` depending on the length of lists.

Comment: `itertools.izip` is indeed a good suggestion for larger datasets. (It would probably cause problems for replacing `zip(d1, d2)[0]` because of the index, but that shouldn't be hard to fix.

Answer (score 3):

*(This answer has the disadvantage of using an external library, but)*

`pandas` already provides extraordinarily powerful and simple tools for dealing with csv files.  You can use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Note your data structure is structured awkwardly, so we first transform it to a more intuitive structure

```
data_set2 = { x.keys()[0] : x.values()[0] for x in data_set }

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data_set2)
df.to_csv('names.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Someone else must have downvoted, you can only hope they come back to check.

Answer (score 2):

**This code will help you without being tied to a certain number of dicts inside `data_set`**

> I've added another dict with 'Losses' key, to test

```
import csv

data_set = [
    {'Active rate': [0.98, 0.97, 0.96]},
    {'Operating Expense': [3.104, 3.102, 3.101]},
    {'Losses': [1.14, 2.28, 3.42]}
]

headers = [d.keys()[0] for d in data_set]

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    for item in zip(*[x.values()[0] for x in data_set]):
        more_results = list()
        more_results.append(headers)
        more_results.append(item)
        writer.writerow(dict(zip(*more_results)))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: "*This code will help you without being tied to a certain number of dicts inside data_set*": I think most other answers were already taking this into consideration.

Comment: @Bruno I don't write code based on other answers. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: Can you make it Python 3 compatible?

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH, sorry, I certainly did not imply plagiarism, just saying that particular point (other dicts in `data_set`) was already handled in other answers. Your answer mainly differs from others in that it still uses a `DictWriter`. I'm not sure it's worth the trouble of rebuilding a dict and using a `DictWriter` at all, it just seems more work.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @PyAn ok, let me see.

Comment: @PyAn I wouldn't necessarily use this answer because the whole stuff with `more_results` and `DictWriter` is a bit overkill, but `headers = [ d.keys()[0] for d in data_set ]` should be a suitable replacement. You'll find Python 3 uses `izip` anyway, so that's [why you can't use an index](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4989890/372643).

Comment: @Bruno maybe you can help me modify my answer instead of encouraging him not to select my answer.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH I've already written an answer that does exactly what you're suggesting without a `dict`. Sorry, I'm not picking on your answer (and my previous comment does suggest how to improve your answer for Python 3), it's just that it came much later than the other answers, differing only from Martin's and my answer by the fact it's using `dict`s and `DictWriter`, which I think just makes things more complicated. I'm not sure whether you or the OP realise that (but it's clear someone wants to start revenge downvoting...)

Comment: To clarify the little point I'm making, you could get this much shorter (and without the need to rebuild a dict) like so: `writer = csv.writer(csvfile); writer.writerow(headers); writer.writerows(zip(*[x.values()[0] for x in data_set]))`. Creating `more_results`, then turning it into a dict with `dict(zip(*more_results))`, which is only required because a `DictWriter` is used seems convoluted, and can be avoided by using a normal `writer` in the first place. That's all I'm saying.