# Python evaluating a function based on contents of a list

Tags: python, list, function

I have grandfathered a code which works has list:

```
A = [ 's1', 's2', 's3', 's1' ] #the actual size is about 200
B = [ 1, 2, 13, 4 ] #same size as A
```

s1, s2, s3 are variables defined on the fly as:

```
s1 = 5
s2 = 3
s3 = 13
```

I have a function defined as:

```
def fun1( s, arg2 ):
 return s * numpy.random.normal( 0, 1, ( 200, arg2 ) )
```

arg2 in above function comes from array B corresponding to s1 selected

I want to generate C such that:

```
C = [ fun1(s1,1), fun1(s2,2), fun1(s3,13), fun1(s1,4) ] #C can be list or collection of arrays, not sure about the best data structure for C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built in function `zip()` to combine `A` and `B` into a list of tuples, before using a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

s1 = 5
s2 = 3
s3 = 13

A = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's1']
B = [1, 2, 13, 4]

def fun1(s, arg2):
 return s * np.random.normal(0, 1, (200, arg2))

C = [fun1(locals()[A_item], B_item) for A_item, B_item in zip(A, B)]
```

Comment: I'd say `izip` instead of `zip`, otherwise +1

Comment: I haven't come across `izip` - is it more efficient?

Comment: [Depends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989763/when-is-it-better-to-use-zip-instead-of-izip). `izip()` is the generator version, so it won't construct an actual list. Given you're passing it to the list comprehension, you don't need the actual zipped list, you'll be discarding it at the end anyway.

Comment: `izip` doesn't even exist any more in modern Python (`zip` does what it used to).

Comment: @Vlad only is you are in python 2, in python 3 zip is the same as izip in 2

Comment: Ah, I actually didn't know that. I knew they'd done this for `xrange` vs `range`, but I tend to use Python 2 more than I should. Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: @Vlad in that case also know that they do the same with filter and map :)

Comment: That makes me happy! I always found having to import those awkward.

Answer (score 2):

Use `locals()['s1']` to access the value of `s1` given the string `s1`, if `s1` is a local variable.

Use `globals()` if `s1`, `s2`...,`s4` are global variables.